# Implementation of Ledoit Wolf shrinkage estimator within R package tawny

Tags: programming, covariance-estimation

I want to implement the shrinkage intensity given by Ledoit and Wolf, see [here](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAAahUKEwj1_M6okNTIAhVLWT4KHRp9BG4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ledoit.net%2Fhoney.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHfL9Xy38qWLTs_9ClJTzpxHRnkHw&sig2=yLAyJUYZkCVCMoB793Am4w) page 13. They define $y_{it}$ with $1\le i\le N$ and $1\le t\le t$ be the return on stock $i$ at time $t$. Moreover, $z_i:=\bar{y}_i:=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^Ty_{it}$ the mean estimator of the $i$-th stock. 
As they explain the optimal shrinkage intensity estimator is given by (for simplicity I drop the hat notation)

$$\kappa = \frac{\pi-\rho}{\gamma}$$

I have a question about the implementation of $\pi$. They define

$$\pi_{ij} = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T((y_{it}-z_i)(y_{jt}-z_j)-s_{ij})^2$$

I wanted to implement this in a efficient way. The package 'tawny' has a preimplemented function of this. I checked the source code, which can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/tawny_2.1.2.tar.gz) in the file shrinkage.R. They use (I copy):

```
# Sum of the asymptotic variances
# returns : T x N (zoo) - Matrix of asset returns
# sample : N x N - Sample covariance matrix
# Used internally.
# S <- cov.sample(ys)
# ys.p <- shrinkage.p(ys, S)
shrinkage.p <- function(returns, sample)
{
  T <- nrow(returns)
  N <- ncol(returns)
  ones <- rep(1,T)
  means <- t(returns) %*% ones / T
  z <- returns - matrix(rep(t(means), T), ncol=N, byrow=TRUE)

  term.1 <- t(z^2) %*% z^2
  term.2 <- 2 * sample * (t(z) %*% z)
  term.3 <- sample^2
  phi.mat <- (term.1 - term.2 + term.3) / T

  phi <- list()
  phi$sum <- sum(phi.mat)
      phi$diags <- diag(phi.mat)
  phi
}
```

The input is the transposed $y$ as they define it to be a $T\times N$ matrix. 
Their final output I'm interested in is the following:

```
phi.mat <- (term.1 - term.2 + term.3) / T
```

If their code works properly (which for sure it does) its true that $(i,j)$ entry of `phi.mat` is equal $\pi_{i,j}$. However, this is the point I cant figure out why this is true. Since in `R` addition / subtraction of matrices is elementwise it should be true that `term.1` is equal to

$$\sum_{t=1}^T(y_{it}-z_i)^2(y_{jt}-z_j)^2$$

and `term.2` equal to

$$2\sum_{t=1}^T(y_{it}-z_i)(y_{jt}-z_j)s_{ij}$$

and last `term.3` equal to

$$\sum_{t=1}^T s_{ij}^2$$

I understand `term.3`. However, `term.1` and `term.2` are not that clear to me. I guess understanding one of them will help me understand the other. So lets focus on `term.1`:

> **Question** Why is it true that $(i,j)$ entry of their code `term.1` is equal to $\sum_{t=1}^T(y_{it}-z_i)^2(y_{jt}-z_j)^2$? Isn't the matrix product, which they suggest, equal to
>   $$\sum_{t=1}^T(y_{it}-z_i)(y_{tj}-z_j)$$ 
>   and the matrix of returns is clearly not symmetric?

Comment: Maybe some clarification would make it easier to help you. Why do you think that the $(i,j)$ entry is equal to this sum of squared elements? I agree to your point that the output of this small function is the last sum you gave in your question. So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: @muffin1974 the final result in their function is phi.mat, which is a elementwise addition/substraction of three matrices. As far as I see, each term is for one of the terms in $((y_{it}-z_i)(y_{jt}-z_j)-s_{ij})^2$ when expanding the square. May I ask you if you downvoted the question and if so why?

Comment: I understand that the output of this function contains phi.mat and it is correct that the 3 terms are nothing but the parts evolving when expanding the square. However, although I opened the link you provided and I know the Ledoit/Wolf paper I cannot figure out what exactly you want to know, for me this question either lacks some details or is not precisely showing what you are curious about, this is why I downvoted it. However, given you can clarify your problem with this R implementation I am sure that there is some help=)

Comment: @muffin1974 I edited my question and hope the more detailed explanation is fully sufficient now. Let me know if there is still a point of ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you asked can be explained by these two lines of the code

```
e   means <- t(returns) %*% ones / T
z <- returns - matrix(rep(t(means), T), ncol=N, byrow=TRUE)
term.1 <- t(z^2) %*% z^2 e
```

Here returns is TxN which gives you matrix ${y_{nt}}$ where n has i and j elements ; means is TxN of  matrix ${z_i}$ , same mean for each asset for the time series.
Therefore, line 2 of code above gives you z variable which is  matrix ${y_{nt}-z_i}$. When you take a transpose and multiply you get a sum of cross multiplication elements. Elements were squared when you do z^2. therefore you are taking a transpose of matrix of squared elements like $({y_{nt}-z_i})^2$ and multiplying by matrix $({y_{nt}-z_i})^2$. That is how you get cross  multiplication of the squared elements for term.1. Likewise for term 2, the code uses t(z) and not t(z^2) which explains the elements are not squared. I hope this explains it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the "^2" operation is performed element by element in this instance. The matrix square in R is ... um... different. Memory fails me on the exact notation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question slightly. Its not about the square, its about the matrix multiplication itself. I dont understand how they get the correct entries by the multiplication they suggest.